need the 1st VBA line of all my userdefined functoins
out there,
with this little snippet I'm able to list all userdefined functions to a worksheet:
Option Explicit

Public Sub ListProcedures()
    Dim oMod As Object
    Dim i As Integer, iStart As Integer

    Cells.Clear

    i = 1
    For Each oMod In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        With oMod.CodeModule
             If oMod.Name =    "mdlFunctions" Then
                 iStart = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                 Do Until iStart >= .CountOfLines
                     Cells(i, 1) = .ProcOfLine(iStart, 0)
                     Cells(i, 2) = oMod.Type & "*"
                     Cells(i, 3) = oMod.Name
                     iStart = iStart + .ProcCountLines(.ProcOfLine(iStart, 0), 0)
                     i = i + 1
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub

As you'll understand I'll get the name and the type of the procedure. What I need is the entire first line of the code e.g. Public Function KissMe(Sound as a String, Duration as Long, Taste as Byte)
I guess that it's only one line more in my code, but so far I'm helpless.
Thank you very much and have a nice weekend!
researches on the web
I guess just one line of code
THX

My proposal how to adapt your code would be
Public Sub ListProcedures()
    Dim oMod As Object
    Dim i As Integer, iStart As Integer

    Cells.Clear

    i = 1
    For Each oMod In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        With oMod.CodeModule
            If oMod.Name = "mdlFunctions" Then
                iStart = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
                Do Until iStart >= .CountOfLines
                    
                    ' get procedure/function ...  name
                    Dim procName As String
                    procName = .ProcOfLine(iStart, 0)
                    Cells(i, 1) = procName
                    
                    Cells(i, 2) = oMod.Type & " * "
                    Cells(i, 3) = oMod.Name
                    
                    ' Get the complete first line
                    Dim lineNum As Long
                    lineNum = .ProcBodyLine(procName, 0)
                    Cells(i, 4) = .Lines(lineNum, 1)
                    
                    iStart = iStart + .ProcCountLines(.ProcOfLine(iStart, 0), 0)
                    i = i + 1
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub

Further reading
